# JavaScript SVG vector path around brush strokes for a brush selection tool

Tags: javascript, svg

If a user draws a brush stroke [like this](http://perfectionkills.com/exploring-canvas-drawing-techniques/#point-based):

[image: source: http://perfectionkills.com/exploring-canvas-drawing-techniques/#point-based]

I want the SVG vector path around that shape. I'm trying to make a brush selection tool.

Answer (score 2):

One approach is to use vector boolean operations (such as: union and difference), to add and subtract vector shapes. [Paper.js](http://paperjs.org/) has [Boolean Path Operations](http://paperjs.org/reference/pathitem/#unite-path) (e.g. - `shape1.unite(shape2)` and `shape1.subtract(shape2)`). Paper.js is implemented using `<canvas>`, but can be translated to an `<svg>` String or DOM element using `shape.exportSVG()`.

```js
window.onload = function() {
 paper.setup('canvas_id');

 var svg = document.getElementById('svg_id');
 
 var brushRadius = 10;
 var followMouseCircle = new paper.Path.Circle(new paper.Point(0,0), brushRadius);
 followMouseCircle.strokeColor = 'black';
 followMouseCircle.visible = false;
 followMouseCircle.dashArray = [3,3];
 var brushShape;
 paper.view.onMouseEnter = function(event) {
  followMouseCircle.visible = true;
 };
 paper.view.onMouseMove = function(event) {
  followMouseCircle.position = event.point;
 };
 paper.view.onMouseLeave = function() {
  followMouseCircle.visible = false;
 };
 paper.view.onClick = function() {};
 paper.view.onMouseDown = function(event) {
  var circle = new paper.Path.Circle(event.point, brushRadius);
  if (brushShape) {
   // combine this click shape (circle) with cumulative, previous shapes (brushShape)
   var brushShape_clone = brushShape.clone(); // clone is required to remove previous shapes from <canvas>
   brushShape.remove(); // remove previous brushShape from <canvas>
   brushShape = circle.unite(brushShape_clone);
   circle.remove(); // remove circle from <canvas>
   brushShape_clone.remove(); // remove clone from <canvas>
  } else {
   brushShape = circle;
  }
  brushShape.fillColor   = '#777777';
 };
 paper.view.onMouseDrag = function(event) {
  // make drag shape (roundedRectangle)
  var roundedRectangle = new paper.Path.Rectangle({
   point:  [event.point.x-event.delta.length-brushRadius,event.point.y-brushRadius],
   size:   [event.delta.length+2*brushRadius, 2*brushRadius],
   radius: brushRadius
  });
  roundedRectangle.rotate(event.delta.angle, event.point);

  // combine this drag shape (roundedRectangle) with cumulative, previous drag shapes (brushShape)
  var brushShape_clone = brushShape.clone(); // clone is required to remove previous shapes from <canvas>
  brushShape.remove(); // remove previous brushShape from <canvas>
  brushShape = roundedRectangle.unite(brushShape_clone);
  roundedRectangle.remove(); // remove roundedRectangle from <canvas>
  brushShape_clone.remove(); // remove clone from <canvas>
  brushShape.fillColor = '#777777';

  // brush circle
  followMouseCircle.position = event.point;
  followMouseCircle.bringToFront();

  // svg
  svg.innerHTML = brushShape.exportSVG({asString:true});
 };
 paper.view.onMouseUp = function() {
  brushShape.selected = true;
  
  var simplify = false;
  if (simplify) {
   brushShape.simplify(0);
  }

  // svg
  svg.innerHTML = brushShape.exportSVG({asString:true});
 };

};
```

```css
body {
  font-family: monospace;
}
canvas, svg {
  border: dashed 1px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<!-- Load the Paper.js library -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/paper.js/0.10.2/paper-full.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
 &lt;canvas id="canvas_id"&gt;<br/>
 <canvas id="canvas_id" width="400" height="120" resize="true"></canvas>
 <br/>
 &lt;/canvas&gt;<br/>
 &lt;svg id="svg_id"&gt;<br/>
 <svg id="svg_id" width="400" height="120" ></svg>
 <br/>
 &lt;/svg&gt;<br/>
</body>
</html>
```